# List of galaxies with their dark matter halo

Tags: galaxy, universe, space, dark-matter, mass

Where can one find the list of galaxies with their dark halo masses, I've searched several sites but I found no such proper list where the masses of their dark matter halo is compiled?

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

This paper by Wechsler & Tinker (2018) should give you a better direction. Depending on the model, different estimates of DM halos come up. You just need to go through the sections on observational evidence and the underlying papers.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.03097.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean observed or simulated? I assume the former, but observing the mass $M_\mathrm{h}$ of a dark matter (DM) halo is not easy (I mean, they're invisible), so you need a model to relate $M_\mathrm{h}$ to some observable.

#### "Observed" dark matter halos

Typically, such measurements are not made in large bulks, so I don't think you can find a "list". Rather, models are constructed based on theory and a few observations, together with previous observations. Popular ways to obtain $M_\mathrm{h}$ is *abundance matching*, where a property of the DM halos (in this case mass) is assumed to correlate tightly with some observable such as stellar mass/luminosity (e.g. [Reddick et al. 2013](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013ApJ...771...30R); [Behroozi et al. 2013](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013ApJ...770...57B)).

A more direct way is — as discussed in the last section of [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/39537/5264) — to measure the width of emission lines, but in order to convert this into $M_\mathrm{h}$ requires measuring the radius as well, which can only be done for the luminous matter, and is particularly difficult for small, faint galaxies.

#### Clusters and groups of galaxies

Inferring $M_\mathrm{h}$ for clusters of galaxies is easier, I think, as one can be moderately confident that the gas is in hydrostatic equilibrium and hence relate the observed X-ray brightness to halo mass (e.g. [Bhattacharya et al. 2013](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013ApJ...766...32B/abstract)). See also [Yang et al. (2009)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009ApJ...695..900Y).

#### Simulated dark matter halos

I don't know why you need such a list, but if you're okay with (hydrodynamically) *simulated* galaxies, then there are plenty of such catalogues, since in this case we know exactly the masses of their different components. [Joanne Cohn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joanne_Cohn) at Berkeley has compiled a [list of simulated galaxy catalogues](http://w.astro.berkeley.edu/%7Ejcohn/mocklist.html) (note that the list also contains catalogues of dark matter-only simulations).